# How can I USE a JAR file after I added it to a Netbeans project?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a JAR file that contains a class that I need for an assignment. I already added the JAR file using Properties > Libraries > Add JAR. I can see the file and the class inside it (it is in ) in the Projects side panel. But it won't let me create an object for it. It says symbol not found.

Comment: If you tried to create an object, you should get the light bulb that lets you import the correct import for the object.

Comment: i didnt get one.. it just asks me to create a new class

Comment: Try restarting Netbean.

Comment: You can also try I think control + shift + i.

Comment: You could go to the jar and look at its content to see if you are importing and spelling things correctly.

Comment: try to build and update your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the class which you want to use like `import java.util.List;`

Comment: I do not know what import statement to use. It is in the default package but import LetterInventory; (class name) does not work.

Comment: Maybe you should post the error info in the question.